# Add a class to breadcrumb item using partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml, partials

I'm pretty new to rails and haml. I've got a breadcrumb that I want to render with partials and I want to pass a variable to the partial so that the correct item gets the "enabled" class. Here's what I tried:

```
= render 'nav_breadcrumb', :locals => {:page1 => true}
```

and on my _nav_breadcrumb.html.haml page I have this:

```
.overlay-breadcrumb.clearfix
  %span{:class => ("enabled" if :page1)}
    %span 1
  %span{:class => ("enabled" if :page2)}
    %span 2
  %span{:class => ("enabled" if :page3)}
    %span 3
```

The problem is, all 3 are getting the enabled class, regardless of the given render variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this part in the Rails documentation:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Looks like when you pass the variable, you need to write {page1: true}, and then in the template just use the name to refer to the variable.

```
= render 'nav_breadcrumb', :locals => {page1: true}

.overlay-breadcrumb.clearfix
    %span{:class => ("enabled" if page1)}
      %span 1
    %span{:class => ("enabled" if page2)}
      %span 2
    %span{:class => ("enabled" if page3)}
      %span 3
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks! I got a error still but changing 'render' to 'render partial' seems to fix that. Then it complained that page2 and page3 didn't exist so I changed the locals to: {page1: true, page2: false, page3: false} and it worked. Is there a more elegant way than added all the false items as well?